# Footer is not displaying at the end of page based on less/more content in the page

Tags: html, css

I have an application based on the following css.The page is designed to display employee database and their task records.I need the header always at the bottom of the page even the content is less/more in number.I cant fix it.Once when I fix for less content it gets displayed above the content when more contents are added.I need help to fix this...

```
* { padding:0; margin:0; outline:0; }
body {
    background:#f9ebae;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:14px;
    color:#5e5e5e;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
input, textarea, select { font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:13px; }
textarea { overflow:hidden; }

.field { border:solid 1px #d3cfc7; background:#fff; padding:5px; }
.small-field { border:solid 1px #d3cfc7; background:#fff; padding:3px 1px; font-size:11px; }

.checkbox { width:13px; height:13px; vertical-align:top; position:relative; top:2px; }

.button { background:#eee url(images/button.gif) repeat-x 0 0; border:solid 1px #b1a874; color:#7f7f7f; font-size:11px; padding:2px 6px 2px 6px; cursor:pointer; line-height:14px !important; }
.button:hover { color:#333; border-color:#857b42; }


.field:focus { color:#000; border-color:#857b42;}

a img { border:0; }

a { color:#ba4c32; text-decoration: underline; cursor:pointer; }
a:hover { color:#8d341f; text-decoration: none;}

.left, .alignleft { float:left; display:inline; }
.right, .alignright { float:right; display:inline; }
.rights, .alignright { float:right; display:inline; }

.cl { font-size:0; line-height:0; clear:both; display:block; height:0; }

.al { text-align: left; }
.ar { text-align: right; }
.ac { text-align: center !important; }

h1{ font-size:22px; font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; line-height:24px; color:#fff; font-weight: normal;}
h1 a{ color:#fff; text-decoration: none; }
h11{ font-size:32px; font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif; line-height:30px; color:#fff; font-weight: normal;}
h11 a{ color:#fff; text-decoration: none; }
h2 { font-size:15px; font-weight: normal; }
h2 a{ text-decoration: none; }
h22 { font-size:20px; font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif; font-weight: normal; }
h22 a{ text-decoration: none; }
h3 { font-size:12px; color:#3333FF; line-height:14px; font-weight: normal; }
h3 a{ text-decoration: none; }



.shell { ; margin:0; auto; }
#header { height:89px; background:url(images/header.gif); white-space:nowrap; }
#header h1{ float:left; display:inline; padding-top:12px; }
#top-navigation { float:right; white-space:nowrap; color:#fff; padding-top:15px; }
#top-navigation a{ color:#fff; }
#top-navigation span{ color:#dca598; }
#top { height:53px;}

#navigation { height:36px;}
#navigation ul{ list-style-type: none;}
#navigation ul li{ float:left; display:inline; margin-right:2px;}
#navigation ul li a,
#navigation ul li a span { float:left; height:36px; background:url(images/tab.gif) no-repeat 0 0; padding:0 0 0 15px;}
#navigation ul li a span { background-position:right 0; padding:0 15px 0 0;}
#navigation ul li a { line-height:36px; color:#907525; text-decoration: none; }

#navigation ul li a.active,
#navigation ul li a:hover { background-position:0 bottom;}

#navigation ul li a.active span,
#navigation ul li a:hover span{ background-position:right bottom; }

#navigation ul li a.active { font-size:12px; font-weight: bold; color:#887e42; }

#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -4em;
}
#wrapper1 {
    min-height:200%;
    position:relative;
}

#container   { padding:20px 0; padding-bottom:44px;}
#container10 { padding:20px 0; padding-bottom:44px; min-height:100%;}


.small-nav  { color:#978b48; padding-bottom:20px; }
.small-nav a{ color:#6f6636; }


#main { overflow:auto; padding-bottom: 44px; }
#content { float:left; width:98%;  padding:0 0 44px 2px; }
#contents { float:left; width:auto;  padding:0 0 0 300px;  }
#sidebar { float:right; width:225px; }


.table {}
.table th{ background:#fffdfa url(images/th.gif) repeat-x 0 0; color:#818181; text-align: left; padding:7px 10px; border-bottom:solid 1px #d2d1cb;}
.table td{ background:#fbfcfc;  border-bottom:solid 1px #e0e0e0; padding:8px 10px; }
.table tr.odd td{ background:#f8f8f8; }
.table tr:hover td{ background:#fff9e1; }
.table a.ico{ }

.box { background:#fbfcfc; height:auto; width:auto; padding:1px; margin-bottom:20px; }
.box-head { background:#ba4c32; height:32px; color:#fff; padding: 0 10px; line-height:32px; white-space:nowrap; border-bottom:solid 1px #fff; }
.box-head .rights{ padding:10px 0 10px 1px; line-height:13px;}
.box-head .rights label,
.box-head .rights input { float:left; }
.box-head .rights label { padding:4px 0 0 0;}
.box-head .rights input { margin-left:5px;}
.box-head .right{ padding:5px 0 10px 1px; line-height:13px; }
.box-head .right label,
.box-head .right input { float:left; }
.box-head .right label { padding:4px 0 0 0;}
.box-head .right input { margin-left:5px;}

.pagging { height:20px; padding:8px 0px; line-height:19px; color:#949494; }
.pagging a{ background:url(images/pagging.gif) repeat-x 0 0; height:20px; float:left; padding:0 8px; border:solid 1px #d5d5d5; text-decoration: none; color:#949494; margin-left:5px;  }
.pagging a:hover { border-color:#8c3521; background:#ba4c32; color:#fff; }
.pagging span{ float:left; margin-left:5px; padding-top:2px; }


a.ico { color:#9d9c9a; font-size:10px; text-decoration: none; padding:0 0 0 14px; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:0 0; }
a.ico:hover { color:#333;}
a.del { background-image:url(images/delete.gif); margin-left:10px;}
a.edit { background-image:url(images/ed.gif); margin-left:10px;}
a.status { background-image:url(images/i.gif); margin-left:10px;}

.form { padding:15px 10px 5px 10px; }
.form label{ display:block; font-weight: bold; font-size:13px; padding-bottom:4px; }
.form label span{ color:#999; font-weight: normal;}
.form .field { display:block; }
.form .inline-field .field { display:inline;}
.form .req { font-size:13px; float:right; white-space:nowrap; color:#999;  }
.form p{ padding-bottom:15px; }

.size1 { width:716px; }
.size2 { width:80px; }
.size3 { width:120px; }
textarea.size1 { height:180px; }

.buttons { text-align: right; padding:10px; background:#eee; border-top:solid 1px #e0e0e0; }
.buttons .button{ margin-left:3px;}

.box-content { padding:10px; }

.sort { border-top:solid 1px #e0e0e0; padding-top:10px; margin-top:15px;   }
.sort label{ display:block; font-weight: bold;}
.sort .field{ display:block; margin-top:5px; }
.sort select.field{ width:203px; }


.box-content p { padding-top:10px; }
.select-all{}
.select-all label{ text-decoration: underline; padding-left:4px; }

.add-button,
.add-button span { float:left; height:26px; background:url(images/add-button.gif) no-repeat 0 0; padding:0 0 0 28px; }
.add-button span { background-position:right 0; padding:0 10px 0 0; }
.add-button { font-weight: bold; font-size:12px; color:#747474; text-decoration: none; line-height:26px; }
.add-button:hover { color:#333;}


#footer { height:44px; margin-top: -44px; background:url(images/footer.gif); line-height:44px; width:100%; color:#fff; position:relative; bottom:0; left:0; clear:both; }
#footer a{ color:#fff;}
#footer, #push {
height: 4em;
}
#footer, #push {
clear: both;
}

.msg { position:relative; padding-right:35px; margin-bottom:10px; }
.msg p{ padding:9px 10px 9px 40px; font-size:12px; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:10px 5px;}
.msg a.close{ font-size:0; line-height:0; position:absolute; top:0; right:0; width:34px; height:34px; background:url(images/close.gif); text-indent: -4000px;}

.msg-ok p{ background-color:#fffac2; border:solid 1px #dbd6a2; color:#5e5c40; background-image:url(images/ok.gif); }
.msg-error p{ background-color:#f3c598; border:solid 1px #e8b084; color:#ba4c32; background-image:url(images/msg-error.gif);  }

/*** CSS3 ***/
.box { -moz-border-radius:5px; -webkit-border-radius:5px; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #978f6c; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #978f6c;}
.box-head { -moz-border-radius-topleft:5px; -moz-border-radius-topright:5px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px; }

.field, .button { -moz-border-radius:4px; -webkit-border-radius:4px; }
.small-field, .button, .pagging a { -moz-border-radius:3px; -webkit-border-radius:3px; }

.msg p { -moz-border-radius:6px; -webkit-border-radius:6px; }

.button { -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #978f6c; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #978f6c;}

.rrshow{
    display:none;
}

<!--Print query css-->

@media print
{
    .print-hidden {
        display: none;
    }

    a {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: header at the bootom ? or at footer at the bottom ?

Comment: Please add your html also. You can quickly build a demo with e.g. http://jsfiddle.net (just paste in your html and css and click Save)

Comment: @Shah Rukh-Sorry Its footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to position it at the bottom

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
```

Comment: I tried this but when content gets loaded the footer displays above the content itself.The footer position doesnot changes when using this query.

Comment: I fixed it by applying min-height to content & the footer got adjusted to the bottom of the page. Thanx a lot for your help & guidance guys.

Comment: @VRR good to hear that VRR if my answer was useful please accept if it does not just leave it.

Comment: @JohnYour answer helped me to fix that issue in one of my pages.Thank U 4 that...